# How can I change the state only after the API response is available in props from redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a scenario where I am calling an action (which further calls and API) and saves the result in store to be accessed using props from connect API of 'react-redux'.

My challenge is that after triggering an action I need to call `this.setState()` method to change the state and then access the new state in my render component.

I believe that I am trying to mutate the state even before the data is available in component props from reducer.

I thought of trying promises i.e using `.then()` method and then changing the state. Like this:

```
this.props.dispatch(getUsers()).then(this.setState({rows:this.props.reducer.users}))
```

But it only gave me below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Please tell me how can I solve this problem

```
import React, {Component} form 'react';
import {getUsers} from './actions/action_info.js'
import Table from './components/table.js'

class MyComponent extends Component{

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={rows:[]}
}

componentDidMount(){
//calling an action here
this.props.dispatch(getUsers())
//mutating the the state
this.setState({rows:this.props.reducer.users})
}

render(){
return(
<Table rows={this.state.rows} />
)}
}

const mapStateToProps= (state) =>
({
reducer:state.reducer_info
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

I am expecting Data in my component props but it is empty.

Comment: I'd question why you'd copy a property straight into your state as a variable. Why not just reference it directly from the props?

Comment: I assume you're using redux-thunk or redux-saga. Could you add the code of getUsers() so we can check how it works? At first sight, the .then() version should work, but it depends on a correct getUsers implementation which returns the right promise.

Answer (score -1):

you can use componentDidUpdate life cycle method like below.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.reducer.users.length !== prevProps.reducer.users.length) {
    this.setState({rows:this.props.reducer.users})
  }
}
```